# async/await with Try and Catch block

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await, expo, try-catch

I am fetching a user's location from Expo. While catch block always executes first and later location is still fetched correctly. Though, catch should happen only if the location was not fetched.

PS: It happens only when I am testing the app on real device under a Tunnel connection. However, works fine on the Emulator.
I don't see anything wrong with the Code though.

Please comment.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const verifyPermissions = async () => {
    const result = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
    if (result.status !== 'granted') {
      Alert.alert(
        'Insufficient permissions!',
        'You need to grant location permissions to use this app.',
        [{ text: 'Okay' }]
      );
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  };
  (async () => {
    const hasPermission = await verifyPermissions();
    if (!hasPermission) {
      return;
    }
    try {
      const location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      setPickedLocation({
        latitude: location.coords.latitude,
        longitude: location.coords.longitude,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      Alert.alert('Could not fetch location!', 'Please try again.', [
        { text: 'Okay' },
      ]);
    }
  })();
}, []);
```

Comment: Try moving this piece of code

 `const hasPermission = await verifyPermissions();
if (!hasPermission) {
    return;
} `
into the try-catch block

Comment: @PedroFeltrin Sorry, still same issue

Comment: `[{ text: err.message }]`

Comment: @hoangdv Thanks. Error says: LOCATION PROVIDER IS UNAVAILABLE. MAKE SURE THAT LOCATION SERVICES ARE ENABLED.

Comment: @hoangdv Location services do get enabled right after this catch block is executed. I even set the location accuracy value to the lowest level